# How do I find the component of the acceleration in the direction tangent to the curve?

Tags: vectors

I am given the position vector $r(t) = (5cos3t) i + (6t) j + (5sin3t) k$. I am asked to **find the component of the acceleration in the direction tangent to the curve and hence deduce the direction of acceleration relative to the curve.**

In the earlier parts of the question I was asked to find the $(i) velocity$, $(ii) speed$, $(iii) distance\quad travelled$, $(iv) acceleration$, $(v) magnitude \quad of \quad acceleration$.

I am not sure what the question is asking, is it asking me to find the tangential component of acceleration because I tried it but it doesn't make sense. How do I go about this question? Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find the acceleration:

$$\vec a (t)=\ddot {\vec r}(t)=-45\cos (3t) \vec i -45 \sin (3t) \vec k$$

Next, find the direction that is tangent to the parametric curve at time $t$:

$$\vec \tau (t)= \dot {\vec r}(t)=-15\sin (3t) \vec i +6 \vec j + 15 \cos (3t) \vec k$$

Normalize to get $$\frac{\vec \tau (t)}{|\vec \tau (t)|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{261}}\bigl(-15\sin (3t) \vec i +6 \vec j + 15 \cos (3t) \vec k\bigr)$$

To get the *magnitude* of the component of acceleration in the direction of the tangent, compute the dot product of the two (this essentially gives the projection of one vector on to another):

$$\vec a (t) \cdot \frac{\vec \tau (t)}{|\vec \tau (t)|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{261}}\bigl(675\cos (t)\sin (t)+0-675\cos (t)\sin (t)\bigr)=0$$

This shows that the acceleration has no component in the tangent direction. Indeed,[image]

Here, I have plotted $\vec r (t)$ in green, the position at a particular time ($t=1/4$) in white, its acceleration in blue and the tangent (which is also its velocity) in red.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: @glowstontrees hi sorry but how come when you differentiated r(t) shouldnt it be -15sin3t i + 6 j + 15cos3t k? Is it a typo error or am i missing out something?

Comment: Ah yes your right, sorry about that

Comment: sorry the 4th equation as well theres a typo error right? its supposed to be 675sin3tcos3t i - 675cos3tsin3t k?

Comment: Yeah I was fixing that

Comment: thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I might’ve waited to normalize until after computing $\vec a\cdot\vec\tau$.